# use $ sign in .env file values in nodejs

Tags: node.js, dotenv

dotenv skipping environment variable values after the dollar string.

Sample Values

`key=SomeValue$kld`

when i try to read the **key**(process.env.key) inside my nodejs the value will be **SomeValue**.

Am using **dotenv** node module.

How to overcome this issue? Tried base64 encoding keeping it in .env file. the result is still same. tried escaping(**key=SomeValue$kld**) also but result still the same.

Comment: try key="SomeValue$kld"

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: so it seems like it needs to be in single quotes or escape the $ maybe -> https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/214

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this issue as well in Node.  The suggestion [here](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/214#issuecomment-144181101) in the issue linked by @digitalniweb worked.  Simply wrap your string in single quotes like so:

`key='SomeValue$kld'`

This also works when you have a pound sign (#) in your string e.g. (`key='passw#rd'`).